# I have a "None" code when I try to catch a tag in HTML content with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, http, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests, bs4, html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://trouver-ip.com"
ip = input("Choisissez une IP : ")
response = requests.post(url, data={"ip": ip})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
print(response)

def compare():
    if soup.find("tbody"):
        tableau = soup.findAll("html")
        return(tableau)
    else:
        print("Aucun résultat, foirage de code masturbin")
    

tableau = compare()
print(tableau)
```

Whatever what I put at the place of "html" in tag search. I tried many tag that I'm sure they are in the HTML content, but my code don't found anything. By the way, when I try I have my "else" message with the print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for the `table` instead of `tbody`,

```
def compare():
    tableau = soup.find("table"):
        return tableau
    else:
        return "Aucun résultat, foirage de code masturbin"
```

Comment: Holy shit thanks you, I had to modify just a lot but you very helped me more than the entire web...

By the way, how do you extract just one tag for presentation ?

One time more, thanks you